# Как вернуть значение из функции при работе с vk api js?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Работаю с vk api. Написал функцию которая работает и получает массив друзей.

```
function getFriends(id) {


    VK.init({
        apiId: my_id;
    });

    VK.Api.call('friends.get', {user_id: id, fields: ['uid']}, function(r) {
        if(r.response) {
            return r.response;
        }else{
            alert("Не удалось получить список друзей!")
        }

    });
}
```

Пытаюсь получить этот массив в другой функции, но значение undefined

```
function func() {
    var arr1 = getFriends(1); // вот здесь undefined вместо массива
}
```

Как правильно вернуть массив?

Comment: Не уверен, но вроде бы в текущем примере кода вы возвращаете r.response.response, а не r.response.

Comment: Там конечно же просто return r.response;
r = r.response; - эта строка лишняя.
Ошибка все равно

Comment: `VK.Api.call` асинхронный и значение вы не вернёте никак, учите асинхронщину

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо, буду знать в какую сторону смотреть.

Comment: @andreymal получается нет вообще способа вернуть значения никакие? Или есть все же какие-то методы? ( callback или еще что-то)?

Comment: Собственно, `function(r)` это и есть callback :)

Comment: @andreymal а есть механизм чтобы выполнить это присвоение, только когда данные придут, тоесть колбэк сработает. Как вобще это реализовать ?

function func() {
    var arr1 = getFriends(1); // вот здесь undefined вместо массива
}